# Problem with nvidia + monitor (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors

I have my laptop connected through HDMI to a monitor. I have a video-card nvidia RTX-2070.
The monitor shows: `"Not Optimum Mode. Recommended mode 3440x1440"`.
My current Display-Mode is `Mirror` and I can't choose the recommended resolution since it's not in the options to choose from (I believe it's showing me the possible resolutions for my laptop screen).
If I choose `Join Displays` then I can see the mouse in the monitor but the rest of the screen is black, and after a few seconds the settings is reverted.
I tried installing recommended nvidia-drivers. First I run `ubuntu-drivers devices` I get:

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001F10sv00001043sd00001711bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : TU106M [GeForce RTX 2070 Mobile]
manual_install: True
driver   : nvidia-driver-440 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-440-server - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-435 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-418-server - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

Then `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-440-server` but afterwards every time I boot I received:

```
/dev/..  clean, nnn/nnn files, nnn/nnn blocks
```

And the only way to boot again is to enter recovery mode and doing a `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`

(I also tried using `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-435` instead, with same results).

*Note: I tried the monitor with the same laptop with Windows 10 (I have dual boot) and the monitor worked fine.
I also tried the monitor with a different laptop and Ubuntu 16.04 and the monitor worked fine too.*

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem, have you found any solution?